# Java: show the success message of form submission via session object or URL parameter?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I am doing a java web project with Spring framework.

I am aware of two ways of showing the success message of form submission.

1. Session object:

in java:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("msg", "Success");
```

in jsp:

```
<c:if test="${not empty sessionScope.msg}"> 
    ${sessionScope.msg}
    <% session.removeAttribute("msg"); %>
</c:if>
```

2 URL parameter

At the end of processing in the servlet, redirect to a url with the success message as its parameter.

in java:

```
return "redirect:/form/"?msg=Success";
```

in jsp:

```
${param.msg}
```

I would like to know, from the system design perspective for a big-traffic website, which approach should be preferred and why if possible.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: If you want to maintain some status throughout the application means you can use Session object otherwise URL parameter is enough to carry status.

Comment: Surendar, do you happen to know of any impact of each approach? Especially in a large-scale web application?

Comment: Session should be handled very carefully in large scale applications, handling sensitive things in session is good idea(Ex.Login Id).

Answer (score 2):

Spring MVC has a notion of flash messages which are specially designed for carrying model attributes across redirects. To use them, declare a [`RedirectAttributes`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html) parameter for your handler method.

```
public String handleForm(..., RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("msg", "Success");
    return "redirect:/form";
}
```

The `"msg"` attribute will be added to the model automatically after the redirect has occurred and removed.